# Configuring postfix to use smarthost

Tags: postfix, smtp, centos7, smarthost

I have an application running on centOS 7, which needs to be configured to send mail(postfix) to a third party SMTP server. I have found that a way to accomplish this is to configure a smarthost using the `relayhost`parameter. But how do I set a specific from address for the mails sent from this server?

Comment: Usual approach: Configure the mail-sending app to set the address you want.

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite sender addresses with [`sender_canonical_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_canonical_maps).

For example:

```
sender_canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
```

Which file will contain the [canonical](http://www.postfix.org/canonical.5.html) mappings you want, for instance:

```
root            no-reply@example.com
@example.net    somebody@example.com
```

And you generate its hash in the usual way:

```
postmap /etc/postfix/canonical
```

See the [documentation](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) for more.

Comment: I've tried this out and shot a test mail, Don't know whether it'll work yet, or if the other configurations i've done are appropriate either. Appreciate the help. Thank you.